# Unable to flash factory ROM on Pixel

Tags: factory-image, google-pixel

I'm trying to restore the factory ROM on my Pixel. I've downloaded and unpacked a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/images) for my phone, and when I run `sudo ./flash-all.sh` I get `FAILED (remote: partition [bootb] doesn't exist)`. Here's the whole transcript. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

```
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'bootloaderb' (32728 KB)...
OKAY [  0.836s]
writing 'bootloaderb'...
(bootloader) Valid bootloader version.
OKAY [  1.600s]
finished. total time: 2.435s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  8.593s]
finished. total time: 8.693s
< waiting for any device >
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'radiob' (57192 KB)...
OKAY [  1.428s]
writing 'radiob'...
OKAY [  0.909s]
finished. total time: 2.337s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.006s]
finished. total time: 0.106s
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.img'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
archive does not contain 'vendor.sig'
wiping userdata...
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 122633060352
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8192
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 32768
    Label:
    Blocks: 29939712
    Block groups: 914
    Reserved block group size: 1024
Created filesystem with 11/7487488 inodes and 518062/29939712 blocks
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: 8996-012001-1610061102
Baseband Version.....: 8996-012511-1611190200
Serial Number........: XXXXXXXXXXXX
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.050s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.051s]
checking version-baseband...
OKAY [  0.050s]
sending 'bootb' (24821 KB)...
OKAY [  0.642s]
writing 'bootb'...
(bootloader) Flashing active slot "_b"
FAILED (remote: partition [bootb] doesn't exist)
finished. total time: 1.095s
```

Comment: The only reference I can find to this issue is here, but it's not clear whether anyone solved it: http://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-xl/how-to/verizon-pixel-xl-unlocking-discussions-t3484497/page49

Comment: Try `fastboot flash flash-all.sh` instead? I successfully flashed stock Marshmallow onto my Nexus 6P but now I'm forgetting the specific command...

Comment: Pixel phone/Pixel tablet?

Comment: This was the phone.

Comment: You might want to mention what you have done to your phone so it requires reflashing. Also is your phone a generic Google version or is it a carrier branded version?

Comment: It was a generic google version. Unfortunately I don't know how I got it into that state. Some combination of rooting it, trying to unroot it, and trying to flash the factory ROM. My hope was that "partition [bootb] doesn't exist" would suggest some simple command to repartition the whole world, but I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue you did, and after finding nothing about it online, became panicked that there was a defect with my phone.

Instead, I realized that the version of ADB I had installed on my computer was out of date. I downloaded [a newer version from Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html) and tried the process again. It worked fine and I was able to restore my phone.

Comment: Interesting, I was using the Arch android-tools package, so I don't think it was out of date, but definitely possible.

Comment: had the same issue, was on version 1.0.36, then I upgraded to version 1.0.39 and flashing worked like a charm! thank you (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. (Using Ubuntu Linux) At first, I was getting the "Fastboot too old" error. I was able to bypass this error by running the fastboot commands manually, rather than from the ./flash-all.sh script file.

Then I found that I was getting the error stated above when running `sudo fastboot update image-marlin-opm4.171019.021.d1.zip`. To resolve it, I had to uninstall fastboot, adb and android-sdk-platform tools from my system (assuming they were the old versions that the CLI was trying to use instead of the new version I had just downloaded in to my ~/platform-tools folder. (Under Ubuntu just using `sudo apt-get remove adb fastboot android-sdk-platform-tools`, other distros may require a different command, ie. pacman for Arch, Manjaro). After this was done, just in my home directory, to verify that fastboot had been uninstalled, typed `sudo fastboot devices`, which returned command not found error, this is good.

Then I navigated to my ~/platform-tools directory and ran `sudo ./fastboot update image-marlin-opm4.171019.021.d1.zip` which directly uses the fastboot application in that directory and it all worked fine then.

Output:

```
ewan@obiwan:~/platform-tools$ sudo ./fastboot update
image-marlin-opm4.171019.021.d1.zip extracting android-info.txt (0 MB)
to RAM...
--------------------------------------------        Bootloader Version...: 8996-012001-1711291800 Baseband Version.....:
8996-130091-1802061512 Serial Number........: HT69J0201460
--------------------------------------------        Checking product                                   OKAY [  0.050s] Checking version-bootloader                       
OKAY [  0.050s] Checking version-baseband                         
OKAY [  0.050s] extracting boot.img (29 MB) to disk... took 0.180s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig' archive does not contain
'boot_other.img' archive does not contain 'dtbo.img' archive does not
contain 'dt.img' archive does not contain 'odm.img' archive does not
contain 'product.img' archive does not contain 'recovery.img'
extracting system.img (1762 MB) to disk... took 16.977s archive does
not contain 'system.sig' extracting system_other.img (551 MB) to
disk... took 5.994s archive does not contain 'system.sig' archive does
not contain 'vbmeta.img' extracting vendor.img (251 MB) to disk...
took 2.891s archive does not contain 'vendor.sig' archive does not
contain 'vendor_other.img' Sending 'boot_b' (30173 KB)                
OKAY [  0.851s] Writing 'boot_b'                                  
OKAY [  0.301s] Sending sparse 'system_b' 1/4 (524284 KB)         
OKAY [ 14.661s] Writing sparse 'system_b' 1/4                     
OKAY [  4.363s] Sending sparse 'system_b' 2/4 (524284 KB)         
OKAY [ 13.404s] Writing sparse 'system_b' 2/4                     
OKAY [  3.584s] Sending sparse 'system_b' 3/4 (524284 KB)         
OKAY [ 13.773s] Writing sparse 'system_b' 3/4                     
OKAY [  4.445s] Sending sparse 'system_b' 4/4 (231592 KB)         
OKAY [  6.100s] Writing sparse 'system_b' 4/4                     
OKAY [  1.612s] Sending sparse 'system_a' 1/2 (524284 KB)         
OKAY [ 13.654s] Writing sparse 'system_a' 1/2                     
OKAY [  3.652s] Sending sparse 'system_a' 2/2 (40680 KB)          
OKAY [  1.133s] Writing sparse 'system_a' 2/2                     
OKAY [  0.400s] Sending 'vendor_b' (257548 KB)                    
OKAY [  6.709s] Writing 'vendor_b'                                
OKAY [  2.661s] Setting current slot to 'b'                       
OKAY [  0.089s] Rebooting                                          
Finished. Total time: 118.310s
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the lastest Android7.1.1 fastboot tool to flash images. I have successfully flashed the Pixel 7.1.1 (NMF26Q, Dec 2016) today.

Comment: So, got any Links, Documentation, Screenshots, Or Anything?

Comment: Yes I assume flashing the stock ROM just works for most people. But it didn't work for me, and my question is about how to fix it.